# Interpolation for 3x21525 array

Tags: python, arrays, interpolation

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xDist,yDat,density = np.genfromtxt('asd.csv', delimiter = ',', usecols= (14,15,10), unpack =True, skip_header = 1)
df = pd.DataFrame({"Horizontal_Distance_x": xDist, "Raw_y_data": yDat, "Density": density})
df.drop(df[(df.Raw_y_data <= 590000) | (df.Horizontal_Distance_x < 500000) | \
           (df.Horizontal_Distance_x > 1500000)].index, inplace=True)
density_d = df.Density/1000
yDat_y=(-1000000+df.Raw_y_data)/1000
xDist_x=(df.Horizontal_Distance_x-500000)/1000
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Horizontal_Distance_x": xDist_x, "Raw_y_data": yDat_y, "Density": density_d})

df.to_csv("x_y_density.csv", index=False)
df2.to_csv("x_y_density2.csv", index=False)

plt.xlim([0,1000])
plt.xticks(range(0,1001,200))
plt.ylim(-400,0)
plt.grid(True)
plt.scatter(df2.Horizontal_Distance_x, df2.Raw_y_data, s=10)
```

So, the variables in the Raw_y_data reaches up to -375.01 in the "x_y_density2.csv", I just want to interpolate this number to -400. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of input/code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: + which tools, language

Comment: Python. Sorry, new learner here.

Comment: Update your original post with all required informations: click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75721696/edit)

Comment: Your question had some severe code formatting problems, so I edited to format the code with proper code markdown. Can you verify that my edit accurately represents your code?

Comment: You want to interpolate `Raw_y_data` to -400. Taking that as an x-variable (independent), what is your y-variable (dependent)?

Comment: I see you plot Raw_y_data versus Horizontal_Distance_x. But if Horizontal_Distance_x is your x-variable, then you can't really choose to interpolate Raw_y_data to -400: it is the x-variable you pick a value for, then interpolate to find what y-value corresponds to that. Given your question about Raw_y_data, inverting the variable meanings (and thereby the scatter plot) makes more sense.

Comment: Also, you mention "reaches up to -375.01". I don't know what other values there are, but it sounds like you mean "reaches *down* to -375.01" (not up), and you want to *extrapolate* to -400. Can you confirm or reject whether that is the correct interpretation (and perhaps clarify in your question)?

Comment: You should reduce your code to a [mcve]: the `to_csv()` calls are irrelevant for your question; and so is the plotting code (unless you add a relevant plot, which clarifies the overall problem; see also my previous comment).

Comment: Thank you, it is represent my code correctly.

Comment: I presume that interpolation is the right tool to use for my problem but I do not know actually. Sorry, I want to fix the yDat_y data to -400. My bad, it should be also down to -375.01. [xDist_x, yDat_y, Density_d]=3x21525=[0, -375.01, 3.3]...[312.5, -343.76, 3.3]...[1000, -.05, 2.8]. (The data comes from the meshes and there is no mesh at the -400). Is it clear now?

Comment: To confirm: you want to find the value of `Horizontal_Distance_x` which corresponds to `Raw_y_data == 400`?

Comment: Basically, yes!

Comment: One more question for clarification: there are just two arrays (or columns), `Horizontal_Distance_x` and `Raw_y_data`. Why the mention of a 3 x 21525 array in the title? Are both these columns not one-dimensional? (I think a two-dimensional column is likely to fail anyway in the comparison in the `df.drop(...)` line.)

Comment: There is also 'Density'

Comment: Ok. But I assume you want to extrapolate one at a time; my answer only considers a one-dimensional extrapolation. If you want to extrapolate `Horizontal_Distance_x` as function of *both* `Raw_y_data` and `Density`, then you need a multi-dimensional interpolator (SciPy has these as well). If you want to extrapolate `Density` as function of `Raw_y_data` instead (different thing), you can just apply the same procedure as for `Horizontal_Distance_x`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear, partly because your plot has `Raw_y_data` versus `Horizontal_Distance_x`, while it is `Raw_y_data` that you want an (extrapolated) value for, not the x value. (I also assume you mean extrapolation, not interpolation. But since we can't see your data, nor is there a figure showing the data, there is a bunch of guesswork in this answer.)

You can use one of the [spline interpolators from SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate.html). For example, `PchipInterpolator`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import PchipInterpolator

interpolator = PchipInterpolator(df2.Raw_y_data, df2.Horizontal_Distance_x)

extrapolated_value = interpolator(-400)
```

Depending on your data and choice of interpolator, you may get a decent approximation, or one that is way off the charts.
There is a bit more on that [in the SciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate/extrapolation_examples.html), with a whole bunch of examples.

Comment: I will look into your suggestions. Thank you for your time and interest. Cheers!